# How to use Google Drive API v3 list function with Python?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I can get all the files from shared folders of my Google Drive:

```
respFiles = drive_api.files().list().execute()
print(*respFiles['files'], sep='\n')
```

Exactly the same list of files I see with this code:

```
page_token = None
while True:
  response = drive_api.files().list(q=None,
                                    spaces='drive',
                                    fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
                                    pageToken=page_token).execute()
  for file in response.get('files', []):
    print('Found file: %s (%s)' % (file.get('name'), file.get('id')))
  page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
  if page_token is None:
    break
```

There are some files in this list which I removed yesterday and they do not exist in the drive. Trash is empty. Why does this happen?

Can you explain how `list()` function works? I've read the documentation, but still don't understand how to use it. To be concrete, explain please, how to get all the files and folders `id`'s of specific folder in sorted by `name` order (the same list as you see when open the drive in browser)?

Comment: If you want to get all the files of a folder you just need to add a [query string](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files#query_string_examples) (parameter `q`). Something along the lines `'{{folder_id}}' in parents` this will get only the files that are inside the folder. 
I still don't understand what you mean by deleted files. You are getting files that you cannot see through the UI? Seems weird for me.

Comment: `You are getting files that you cannot see through the UI?` - Yes, exactly!

Comment: Actually there is a boolean property from the [`Files`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource-representations) resources called `trashed`. Could you maybe try to get it and see if this flag has been set to `true`?

Comment: Through the [`Files.get`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) endpoint.

Comment: I found it `'trashed': False`. `Files.get` returns full list only when set `fields` to '*'.

Comment: So you are saying that the file has been deleted from the UI so you cannot see there, and then when you retrieve that file through the API is present without any flag about is deletion. This seems a little off. When I completely delete a file I cannot retrieve it later. If I trash it without deleting forever it appears with a `true` in the `trashed` flag. Look better to see if the files hav been deleted.

Comment: I created only one folder in UI which I shared with api email. Then I created some `gsheat` documents using api in this folder. Then I removed the file in UI. The result: I don't see the file in UI, but it presents in api `list()`. There are a few files in the shared folder, I can't look better. Try to do the same and you'll get the same result.

Comment: Are you authenticating with the same user as the one that you have deleted the files through the UI?

Comment: Yes.................

Comment: This seems weird for me and on testing it I cannot reproduce it. I would suggest you to contact google support if you have [G Suite](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en).